# Why isnt gravity applied in this script and why does jumping not work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why isn't gravity applied in this script, and why does jumping not work? Whenever I play or try my script the player isn't affected by gravity and I can't jump. If I put the subject above the ground it will stay in that level

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Variables
    public float airSpeedCoefficient = 0.5f;
    public float speed = 6.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;
    public CharacterController controller;

    void Awake()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>(); // you only need this to run once, and it can be costly if you run it each frame
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Feed moveDirection with input.
        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        //Multiply it by speed.
        moveDirection *= speed;

        // is the controller on the ground?
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            //Jumping
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        //Applying gravity to the controller
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        //Making the character move
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set movedirection to a public variable and check what happens when you jump.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting each frame with a brand new `moveDirection` vector and with `Y = 0`.

Then only in probably only **one single frame** you are moving slightly up due to the jump, since as said in the next frame you are using `0` again.

The same for the gravity: You start with `0` (or in the jump frame `8`) and substract `20f / 60f` (assuming 60fps) which is either `-0.333` or `7.333`. Than you multiply this by `Time.deltaTime` which results in `-0.333 / 60f = 0.0055555` or `7.3333 / 60f = 0.1222222`.

Result: You barely ever move on the Y axis!

---

What you should do instead is store the Y value in a field and reduce it bit by bit like e.g.:

```
float Y;

public float midAirSpeed;

void Update()
{
    //Feed moveDirection with input.
    var moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
    //Ale sure the maximum magnitude is 1 also for diagonal movement
    moveDirection = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(moveDirection, 1);
    
    // is the controller on the ground?
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        //Multiply it by speed.
        moveDirection *= speed;

        //Jumping
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            // Store in the class field
            Y = jumpSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            // You might want to give this a minimum value at some point
            // so you don't fall insanely fast when you walk off a cliff ;)
            Y = -gravity;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Multiply it by speed.
        moveDirection *= midAirSpeed;

        //Applying gravity to the class field over time
        Y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    

    // Now use this Y changed over time 
    moveDirection.y = Y;

    //Making the character move
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the response , not only did it fix everything it added the function of in air movement wich i have been scratching my head to do for a while , just 1 problem , there is too much in air control , and this code is quite sophisticated for me as i recently started coding , any ideas might help , again thanks big time

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `in air control`? You want to take input only while grounded? Because otherwise you should already be able to control the object midair

Comment: im talking about controling the object mid-air , i can jump , and my y axis is set to go up and then down , but i can move on the x and z axis while jumping/falling , wich is really great and i had in mind to get it to work , only problem is i need to figuere out to how to have some sort of drag effect becasue as of now i can move along the x and z axis pretty freely/unrealistically and not like other real video games where there is some sort of air drag/constraint

Comment: ah I see .. updated the code .. now you can configure the `speed` and `midAirSpeed` individually ;)

Comment: man your the GOAT , i cant thank you enough . thanks so much for everything ^^